# Foundation 4 orbit customization of the features it provides

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

Is there any way by which i can disable the count 2 of 3 images, disabling the play and pause as well as the timer animation that runs on top right. Currently the carousel is not set to auto play by default, how to change it?
Insteading of hiding it by css why not just diable it and no extra html markup will be written as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul data-orbit data-options="timer_speed:2500; bullets:false; timer_container_class: hide; timer_paused_class: hide; timer_progress_class: hide; slide_number_class: hide;">
  ...
</ul>
```

Pass the customizations in the data-options attribute.
I've reset their classes to .hide, a display: none !important class.

this way, you dont modify the js or css and can go back to default by removing the customizations from data-options.